# Restart server computer with PowerShell Direct and resume the script

Tags: windows, powershell, hyper-v

I am deploying Windows VMs with PowerShell Direct and Hyper-V. The VM has to be restarted several times, and as soon as Windows starts again, the script should resume and run other commands. For example, here is a part of my current script:

```
Invoke-Command  -VMName 'server2.example.com' -Credential $credential -ScriptBlock {
Rename-Computer -NewName 'server2' -Force -Restart
}

Start-Sleep -s 10
```

Right now, I use `Start-Sleep -s 10` to make sure that the machine starts before it resumes running other commands. However, I think that this part is incorrect. Do I maybe need to run `Restart-VM VMNAME` on my machine instead of using the `-Restart` argument in `Rename-Computer -NewName 'svn2' -Force -Restart` in the VM? Or is there a better approach?

My problem is that the script continues running the commands when the machine is still restarting. Therefore, I am receiving errors. This is what I want to solve.

Comment: Does HyperV have some kind of status for whether the machine has booted or not? In VMware I would check whether the guest VM tools are started in a while loop.

Comment: @Ash great idea, I did not think about that. I think that I can check this status and it will help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the correct solution here is to restart the VM from the host computer using `Restart-VM` with the `-Wait` parameter.

So I had to replace this

```
Rename-Computer -NewName 'server2' -Force -Restart
}

Start-Sleep -s 10
```

with this

```
Rename-Computer -NewName 'server2' -Force
}

Restart-VM $myVmName -Wait
```